# Stop location updates by using the last google play services api location

Tags: android, geolocation, listener, google-play-services

I'm building a simple weather application and I'm using the last google play services API to get the location. By calling the following:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

we are able to get the location updates and thanks to the listener:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    // update the location    
}
```

we can succeed in update the location. My issue is that I have a weather app and I should stop the location updates unregistering the listener:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

I wouldn't have any button. One possible solution would be to set an higher possible interval or what do you say about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside your onLocationChanged(), update the location and then unregister the listener, like so :

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

Comment: Perhaps for a weather app should be an acceptable solution. After all the user check the position once

Comment: Yes, getting the location once is enough. If you want, you can give the user an option to refresh at which point, you'll start requesting updates again.